# Best way to change class of column of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Once again a seemingly easy problem, but ... I have this small data frame named “d1" in R:

```
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "SHY"   "75000"
[2,] "IGLIX" “25000"
```

All I want to do is convert the characters in column 2 to numerics. After fiddling with this for an hour all I can figure out that works is:

```
a <- data.frame(d1[,1])
b <- data.frame(as.numeric(d1[,2]))
cbind(a, b)
```

which gives me:

```
  d1...1. as.numeric.d1...2..
1     SHY               75000
2   IGLIX               25000
```

Surely there is an easier way to do this? I tried “apply" unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Ernie Your small data.frame `d1` is a `matrix`.  It can hold only one class.  When there is a character column, all the other columns get converted to that.  If you have only two columns, the best option is `data.frame(Col1= d1[,1], Col2=as.numeric(d1[,2]))`

Comment: @akrun Maybe my question is miscast. I am forming d1 from two lists with: do.call(rbind, c(da, db)). I don’t seem to be able to force the second element of lists da or db to be numeric, which I think would solve my problem.

Comment: @akrun can u please take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423931/extract-data-from-raw-html-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple columns in the matrix, you can do it all at once and convert the columns to their appropriate types at the same time.

```
## set up a matrix
m <- matrix(c("SHY", "75000", "IGLIX", "25000"), 2, byrow=TRUE)
## split by column, convert types, and make data frame
data.frame(
    lapply(split(m, col(m)), type.convert, as.is = TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
#      X1    X2
# 1   SHY 75000
# 2 IGLIX 25000
```

`type.convert()` *converts a character vector to logical, integer, numeric, complex or factor as appropriate* so we need to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to get characters in the first column again.

Comment: Perfect! Solves this problem plus another that is downstream from this issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@akrun’s answer solves this problem:

```
data.frame(Col1= d1[,1], Col2=as.numeric(d1[,2]))
```